# On Ubuntu 12.04 libgazebo_common.so.1 not found

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi
I am using ubuntu 12.04 and have installed gazebo by downloading the tarball file and following what was given on the install page(http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.6/install) but when it comes to the last step: that is typing 'gazebo' into the terminal, this is what I get.

gazebo: error while loading shared libraries: libgazebo_common.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried checking the answers on these pages
http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1438/libgazebo_commonso1-no-such-file-or-directory/
and
http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1071/error-while-loading-shared-libraries/

Both of them had the same question, and their answers worked for the ones who had asked but not for me.
As on the install page my installation was done at the default location, as I didn't specify anything.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2338/on-ubuntu-12.04-libgazebo_common.so.1-not-found/) by [vedmathai](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/310/vedmathai/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-04-11**:
try
source /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

tl;dr:

```
sudo bash -c "echo /usr/local/lib >> /etc/ld.so.conf"
sudo ldconfig
```

First, let's understand the situation:

```
ldd `which gazebo` | grep "not found"
```

That will give you a list of the libraries that the executable needs, but that the loader can't find.  Probably `libgazebo_common.so` will be in that list, likely along with many other `lib_gazebo*` libraries.

If you did a default install, it went into `/usr/local`.  By default, your system loader might be configured *not* to look in `/usr/local/lib`.  To test that, add that directory to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ldd `which gazebo` | grep "not found"
```

If that gives you an empty list, then you're ready to go, in which case you run `gazebo` like so:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH gazebo
```

or:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
gazebo
```

But it's better not to have to remember that.  So you can configure your system to look in `/usr/local/lib` for libraries:

```
sudo bash -c "echo /usr/local/lib >> /etc/ld.so.conf"
sudo ldconfig
```

That should work for gazebo and for anything else that you install to `/usr/local`.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2